# R - New column based on values from other rows in other columns

Tags: r, sum, rows

I have a table of dates and values for each date and I want to do the average in a new column of the values of the three dates before. How can I do this in R?

I have this:

```
date unit_sales 
2013-01-10   1
2013-01-11   1 
2013-01-14   1 
2013-01-18   2 
2013-01-21   1  
2013-01-25   1
```

And I want the average of the three days before (if there is no date available, consider it as in Excel):

```
date unit_sales Average
2013-01-10   1    NA
2013-01-11   1    1
2013-01-14   1    1
2013-01-18   2    NA
2013-01-21   1    2
2013-01-25   1    NA
```

Comment: can you check the mean values

Comment: the values are fine, they take the mean of the three days before. For example 2013-01-14, it takes the day 13,12 and 11 and as there is only info available for 11, the mean value gets to 1

Answer (score 0):

We could use `rollmean`

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df1 %>%
    mutate(Average = rollmean(unit_sales, k= 3, fill = TRUE))
```

Comment: I think this one does the average of the three rows before (and I don't exactly get that) and do not consider the date of the row. I would like something like mean of unit_sales considering date -1, date -2 or date -3